# how to set background in View?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I can't get green line at the left side of RelativeLayout.
If I use Linearlayout, it's OK.
Can anybody help me?

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:onClick="onLayoutClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true">


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/colorline"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@color/green" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/string1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="50dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/colorline"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colorline"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you cannot directly do this to a View. Instead replace it with a ImageView and it should work fine.

Instead of this,

```
            <View
                android:id="@+id/colorline"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@color/green" />
```

Add this,

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/colorline"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@color/green" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines .

```
 <View
                    android:id="@+id/colorline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:background="@color/green" />
```

Hope this will help you . ...

Use Following lines in strings.xml

```
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
```

you will get colors ... 
     #000080
     #000000

Answer (score 0):

add the  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
in RelativeLayout